# How to count the equal elements of 2 different vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, count, equality

I am trying to find a way to count how many elements are equal in 2 different vectors of the same size in c++. The vectors hold structs and i want to compare the equality by a double variable of the struct shown on the example.

And to make it clear. I do NOT want to check if the 2 vectors are equal but only to count how many of their elements are.

The following doesn't work. It gives addresses instead of values. Also If I try to access the dist variable like `pointsA[j].dist` I get an error.

```
vector<struct PointWithDistance*> pointsA, pointsB;

//the struct
struct PointWithDistance {
    Point *p;
    double dist;
};

for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
    if (pointsA[j] == pointsB[j])
        equalCount++;
}
```

Comment: it's a pointer so pointsA[j]->dist

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [std::inner_product](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main () {
   const std::vector a{7, 7, 7, 7};
   const std::vector b{7, 6, 7, 7};

   const auto equalCount = std::inner_product(
      a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0,
      std::plus<>(), std::equal_to<>()
   );

   std::cout << equalCount << " of the elements are equal.\n";
}
```

outputs

```
3 of the elements are equal.
```

It is a generalization of the standard inner product,
using the functions `+` (plus) and `==` (equal_to),
instead of `+` and `*`.
Thus it computes
`0 + (a[0] == b[0]) + (a[1] == b[1]) + ...`.

This uses the fact that `false`/`true` can be interpreted as `0`/`1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<struct PointWithDistance*> pointsA, pointsB;
```

Did you mean to use pointers? If so, you have to do `*(points[A])` (and b) because your current comparison compares the *pointers*, not their content.

Also, does the struct `Point` have an `operator ==` so comparison on the type can be performed??

Do you want to force same positions? say, a vector `{1,2,3}` and a vector `{2,3,4}` by your algorithm will have 0 items equal, do you want that? If not, loop the first vector and use `std::find` (or `std::upper_bound` if the vector is sorted) on each element to the second vector.

Some quick code:

```
template <typename T=int> struct Point
{
 T x,y;
 bool operator==(const T& t) { return (x == t.x && y == t.y); }
};

std::vector<Point<>> p1 = {1,2,3}; 
std::vector<Point<>> p2 = {2,3,4}; 
for(auto& p : p1)
{
   if (std::find(p2.begin(),p2.end(),p) != p2.end())   
   {
    // similar++;
   }
}

// or
assert(p1.size() == p2.size());
for(size_t i1 = 0 ; i1 < p1.size() ; i1++)
{
    if (p1[i1] == p2[i1]) 
    {
    // equal++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution to count the number of duplicates in 2 containers could look like this. Using [`std::transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) to add ([`std::plus<>{}`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus)) the boolean result if an element was found in the container. Note how it can accep two different types of containers as long as their contained type stays the same (e.g. `std::vector<int>` and `std::set<int>`). The length of the containers don't have to be equal. There are two SFINAE implementations to differenciate between the case where `T` is a pointer and where it isn't:

```
#include <algorithm>   //std::find, std::find_if
#include <cstddef>     //std::size_t
#include <functional>  //std::plus, 
#include <iterator>    //std::cbegin, std::cend
#include <numeric>     //std::transform_reduce
#include <type_traits> //std::enable_if_t, std::is_pointer_v

namespace {
    //core implementation for duplicate_count
    template<class C, class F>
    std::size_t duplicate_count_impl(const C& container, F pred) {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::cbegin(container), std::cend(container), std::size_t{}, std::plus<>{}, pred);
    }
}

//returns the number of duplicates in two (different) containers.
//overload for containers where T is a pointer type.
template<typename T, template <typename...> class C1, template <typename...> class C2, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>* = nullptr>
std::size_t duplicate_count(const C1<T>& a, const C2<T> &b) {
    return duplicate_count_impl(b, [&](T ptr_b) -> bool {
        return std::find_if(std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a), [&](T ptr_a) -> bool {
            return *ptr_a == *ptr_b;
        }) != std::cend(a);
    });
}

//returns the number of duplicates in two (different) containers.
//overload for containers where T is not a pointer type.
template<typename T, template <typename...> class C1, template <typename...> class C2, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<T>>* = nullptr>
std::size_t duplicate_count(const C1<T>& a, const C2<T> &b) {
    return duplicate_count_impl(b, [&](T n) -> bool {
        return std::find(std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a), n) != std::cend(a);
    });
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

//[duplicate_count implementations]

struct Point {
    int a, b;

    bool operator==(const Point& other) const {
        return this->a == a && this->b == other.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        std::list<int> v = { 1, 2, 7, 7 };
        std::list<int> u = { 0, 1, 2, 7 };
        std::cout << "list<int>\t number of duplicates: " << duplicate_count(v, u) << '\n';
    }

    {
        auto[a, b, c, d] = std::make_tuple(0, 1, 2, 3);
        std::vector<int*> v = { &b, &c, &d, &d };
        std::vector<int*> u = { &a, &b, &c, &d };
        std::cout << "vector<int*>\t number of duplicates: " << duplicate_count(v, u) << '\n';
    }

    {
        auto[a, b, c, d] = std::make_tuple(
            Point{ 0, 0 }, 
            Point{ 1, 1 },
            Point{ 2, 2 }, 
            Point{ 4, 4 });

        std::vector<Point*> v = { &b, &c, &d, &d };
        std::vector<Point*> u = { &a, &b, &c, &d };
        std::cout << "vector<Point*>\t number of duplicates: " << duplicate_count(v, u) << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> list<int>        number of duplicates: 3
> vector<int*>     number of duplicates: 3
> vector<Point*>   number of duplicates: 3
> ```

Comment: Nice... but the OP's (pseudo) code suggests that he/she is looking for the number of times that elements with the same index are equal. These templates seem too look for the total number of duplicates in two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Your shown solution is good, fast and efficient.

It has some minor problem that can easily be resolved. In your definition `vector<struct PointWithDistance*> pointsA, pointsB;`, variables pointsA and pointsB are vectors, containing pointer to structs.

With pointsA[n] you will get a pointer to the struct. But you want the struct by itself. So you simply need to dereference the gotten pointer. And since you want to access a member of a struct (usually done with variable.member), you can use (*(pointsA[j])).dist or pointsA[j]->dist.

If the size of your vectors are guaranteed the same, then you simply need to update your code to

```
vector<struct PointWithDistance*> pointsA, pointsB;

//the struct
struct PointWithDistance {
    Point *p;
    double dist;
};

for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
    if (pointsA[j]->dist == pointsB[j]->dist)
        equalCount++;
}
```

That is the only thing you were missing.